# How to drop time from continuous scale on line chart

Tags: date, time, charts, format, spotfire

In Spotfire 6.0. I have a continuous scale on Line Chart. It is calculated using `BinByDateTime()` function. That's why I have the time part there, but the time is 0:00:00. Can I somehow drop timepart?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7qpP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have (at least) two options.

1. Create a calculated column for just the date par, `Date([YourDateTimeColumn])` and use this on your axis.
2. `Edit > Column Properties > (Select your Date Time Column) > Formatting > (Select a Date Format without the time)`

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, but unfortunately this tip doesn't work. The thing is my initial date column have no time part. Time part generates when I am changing Date Axis from Categorical to Continuous scale format.

Comment: So your column is of what data type @Alex  can you post sample data

Comment: Column is of Date Type in format day.MM.yyyy.
Example of axis is attached in initial question.
Date like 09.06.2016.
But when I am changing the axis type from categorical to continuous scale - then a 0:00:00 part appears on axis.

Comment: That isn't a valid date format for spotfire @Alex unless you explicitly forced a custom format. When you click `Edit > Column Properties` what is the DataType for this column? I'm betting it says string.

Comment: @Alex can you provide the exact expression you have in your axis.

Comment: Dear @scsimon, I had a lot of work, no time to look  at my issue. So, here are:
1) initial column property: http://paste.pics/df9296998ca1579269fe4c03588cbafd

2) how initial variable looks like: http://paste.pics/303a6916e17a531569472c6cccb6c3f5

3) expression for X-Axis, genertes automatically when I am selecting continuous scale: http://paste.pics/c6f549df9504865a989d5109753f83f6

4) how X-Axis looks like with continuous scale: http://paste.pics/2a9b0b6a0394bcf3cf3e7c39e83fb013

5) how X-Axis looks like with categorical scale:
http://paste.pics/27a2cb29752a011a5c7c9e074bacad57